# Using setState with StatelessWidget

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to use setState with StatelessWidget?
I know that I could be used with StatefulWidget and using a State, but I don't know if there's a way to use it with StatelessWidget.

I think that's a direct question and it doesn't need code to be shown.

If you could help me, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No. That's the whole point of `StatelessWidget`: It doesn't have a state.

Only `StatefulWidget` has a state, and therefore only it has a `setState`.

Answer (score 41):

here is an example of code that makes it possible for a StatelessWidget to update itself, its from an article of Didier Boelens.

https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/09/flutter-internals/

> The following useless code makes possible for a StatelessWidget to
> update itself (as if it was a StatefulWidget but without using any
> setState()), by using the BuildContext …
>
> ```
> void main(){
>     runApp(MaterialApp(home: TestPage(),));
> }
>
> class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
>     // final because a Widget is immutable (remember?)
>     final bag = {"first": true};
>
>     @override
>     Widget build(BuildContext context){
>         return Scaffold(
>             appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Stateless ??')),
>             body: Container(
>                 child: Center(
>                     child: GestureDetector(
>                         child: Container(
>                             width: 50.0,`enter code here`
>                             height: 50.0,
>                             color: bag["first"] ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
>                         ),
>                         onTap: (){
>                             bag["first"] = !bag["first"];
>                             //
>                             // This is the trick
>                             //
>                             (context as Element).markNeedsBuild();
>                         }
>                     ),
>                 ),
>             ),
>         );
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Between us, when you are invoking the setState() method, the latter
> ends up doing the very same thing: _element.markNeedsBuild().

Comment: It should be noted that this code should not be used (just switch the widget to a stateful widget). The referenced article has a big colorful disclaimer stating the code is for demonstration, and shouldn't be used. The only indication of that in this answer is the word 'useless', which is even a downgrade from the wording 'totally useless' from the article.

Answer (score 0):

The given code here will work but note that It wont go into batch processing and is synchronous, If this is cpu(image processing etc) or even IO intensive(reading DB etc.), might crash the `UI`. So not recommended. You can `pass a callback` to any`child stateless widget and use that to update the value in`parent stateful widget` .

Comment: Your answer is not clear. Please try to understand what the questioner is asking about. The question is whether we can use "setState(() {});" in StatelessWidget or not. If Yes, then explain how & if No, then explain why.

Comment: Your answer is not clear. Please try to understand what the questioner is asking about. The question is whether we can use "setState(() {});" in StatelessWidget or not. If Yes, then explain how & if No, then explain why.